# How to send emails in wordpress x days after registration

Tags: php, wordpress, email, buddypress

On our community we want to send some follow ups emails x days after registration, like a tutorial for the use of our platform.

For example, 1 day after registration we teach you how to do something, the day 3 we send you another email explaining another thing... so we can have a follow up with the people, so they don't feel abandon on the community.

**I've been looking around for plugins able to do that with no success.**

So I went into the coding part and see if somehow I can do it. **With a CronJob, and a custom script outside Wordpress of course I can do**, but is not a fancy solution when the platform is to be managed by people with no coding knowledge. I was looking for something where you can add the emails like on the default email section of Wordpress.

I know I should post some things I have tried, but sadly I have not find anything or any solution able to do this.

We are running Wordpress + Buddypress + Learndash.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we here usually don't suggest plugin. For this kinda suggestions please go for the [**Software Recommendations**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site they has a *WordPress* tag. As for a recommendation with this *WordPress* tag.

Now come to the coding concept solution how we can handle sending mail after a certain amount of time. Here I can suggest you a way-

```
function the_dramatist_handle_scheduled_mail( $arg_1 = '', $arg_2 = [] ) {
    wp_schedule_single_event(
        // Here time() is the time when this is firing and 259200s = 72h = 3d
        time() + 259200,
        // Declaring a hook at this point. You can hook any function to this point which you want to fire after three days of any base event.
        'the_dramatist_send_email_after_three_days',
        // You can add number of arguments to the hook also.
        [ $arg_1, $arg_2 ]
    );
    return true;

}
```

Now at this `the_dramatist_send_email_after_three_days` hook you add a function like below to send the email-

```
add_action( 'the_dramatist_send_email_after_three_days', 'the_dramatist_send_email_after_three_days_function', 10, 2 );

function the_dramatist_send_email_after_three_days_function( $arg_1, $args_2 ) {

    $to = 'sendto@example.com';
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $to );
    if ( 1 === get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'after_three_days_email', true ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $subject = 'The subject';
    $body = 'The email body content';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $mail_sent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
    // After sending the email to every person I prefer to put a record.
    if ( $mail_sent ) {
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'after_three_days_email', 1 );

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now after your base event you just call the `the_dramatist_handle_scheduled_mail()` with arguments. This way you can handle scheduled events in WordPress by [`wp_schedule_single_event()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event) function.

Hope this above answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend extend the user profile adding a field with the expiration day. For instance the follow example uses the field _profile_extend_expires. Then you can use meta_query filter to check the expiration day.

Regards,
Ed.

```html
function member_expires_one_day() {

    $date_today = today_date();

    $date_to_expire = new DateTime($date_today);
    $date_to_expire->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $expires = $date_to_expire->format('Y-m-d');

    $args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' =>        '_profile_extend_expires',
                        'value' => $expires,
                        'compare' => '=='
                    ),
        )
    );

    $users = get_users( $args );

}
```